# Find a positive number $C$ such that $f(s)<C\cdot g(s/C)$ for all $s$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f,g:(0,\infty)\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be right-continuous decreasing functions. Assume that 
$$\frac{\inf_{s>0} s+t \cdot f(s) }{\inf_{s>0}s+t\cdot g(s)}<1$$
for all $t>0$.
Find a positive number $C$ such that $$f(s)<C\cdot g(s/C)$$ for all $s$.

Comment: What are the infima being taken over? The entire numerator and the denominator?

Comment: @CJDowd  There are two infimas. $\inf_{s>0} (s+t \cdot f(s)) $ and  $\inf_{s>0}(s+t\cdot g(s))$.